# Extracting the "parent" counter of a sectional unit

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I am interested in finding the "parent" counter of a specific sectional unit. For example, in the following document structure

```
1. A section
1.1 A subsection
1.1.1 A subsubsection
1.1.2 A subsubsection
1.1.2.1 A paragraph
1.2 A subsection
1.2.1 A subsubsection
1.2.1.1 A paragraph
1.2.1.2 A paragraph
1.2.2 A subsubsection
```

the (immediate) "parent" of subsubsection 1.2.1 is (subsection) 1.2. The (immediate) "parent" of (paragraph) 1.1.2.1 is (subsubsection) 1.1.2.

The solution should be

- of the form `\parentlabel` that one can call within some sectional unit;
- be able to work with sectional units that have no parent. For example, if the sectional unit is `\chapter`, with `\thechapter` defined as `\arabic{chapter}`, `\parentlabel` should be empty `{}` (say); and
- flexible enough so that redefinition of (say) counter displays does not play a role. That is, if one chooses to use `-` instead of `.`, the solution should still hold. So I don't think string parsing (using, say, [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring)) would be useful.

Here is one attempt and a minimal playground:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\parentlabel{\relax}% Placeholder for parent counter/level/label
\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\edef\parentlabel{\@currentlabel}\oldsection}%
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\edef\parentlabel{\@currentlabel}\oldsubsection}%
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\edef\parentlabel{\@currentlabel}\oldsubsubsection}%
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\edef\parentlabel{\@currentlabel}\oldparagraph}%
\newcommand{\showparent}{Current: \@currentlabel; Parent: \parentlabel}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\section{A section} \showparent
\subsection{A subsection} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\paragraph{A paragraph} \showparent
\subsection{A subsection} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\paragraph{A paragraph} \showparent
\paragraph{A paragraph} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\end{document}
```

The method relies on capturing `\@currentlabel` before it is updated via a sectional command.

It is obvious that this methods works fine while drilling down the sectional levels. However, stepping back to a higher level leaves `\parentlabel` to not accurately represent the "parent" label.

Comment: Also it wouldn't work for classes with chapters.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: This is true. I'm hoping I could generalize it myself once I have something established that solves this for `article`.

Comment: Hint: in a section, \thesubsection ends in `.0` if you're not in a subsection.

Answer (score 15):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\determinecurrentlevel{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    0
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      1
    \else
      \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
        2
      \else
        \ifnum\value{paragraph}=0
          3
        \else
          4
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\showparent{%
  \ifcase\determinecurrentlevel
  \or
    \ifdefined\chapter\thechapter\fi
  \or
    \thesection
  \or
    \thesubsection
  \or
    \thesubsubsection
  \or
    \theparagraph
  \fi}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\section{A section} \showparent
\subsection{A subsection} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\paragraph{A paragraph} \showparent
\subsection{A subsection} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\paragraph{A paragraph} \showparent
\paragraph{A paragraph} \showparent
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} \showparent
\end{document}
```

The long concatenation of conditionals can be reduced with `\numexpr`:

```
\def\determinecurrentlevel{%
  \numexpr
    \ifnum\value{section}>0       1+\fi
    \ifnum\value{subsection}>0    1+\fi
    \ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0 1+\fi
    \ifnum\value{paragraph}>0     1+\fi
  0\relax}
```

Answer (score 13):

A flexible approach would be to define hooks in every sectioning command indicating the parent counter, without worrying for any formatting, which will be available in the relevant `\the` command such as `\thesection`. Suggestion:

```
\@namedef{part}{}
\@namedef{parent@chapter}{\the\c@part}
\@namedef{parent@section}{\the\c@chapter}
\@namedef{parent@subsection}{\the\c@section}
\@namedef{parent@subsubsection}{\the\c@subsection}
\@namedef{parent@paragraph}{\the\c@subsubsection}
```

What you store in the `parent@section` macros depends on your needs. You can store only the `c@section` part, if you want to do any detail manipulation after that. It is just a way of creating a pointer to the parent.

We also define two convenience macros for testing:

```
\def\sectionlist{part,chapter,section,subsection,
    subsubsection,paragraph}
\def\checkall{\@for\next:=\sectionlist\do{
      \next\ has parent = \csname parent@\next\endcsname\\
 }
```

The full minimal is shown below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\def\sectionlist{part,chapter,section,subsection,
    subsubsection,paragraph}
\@namedef{part}{}
\@namedef{parent@chapter}{\the\c@part}
\@namedef{parent@section}{\the\c@chapter}
\@namedef{parent@subsection}{\the\c@section}
\@namedef{parent@subsubsection}{\the\c@subsection}
\@namedef{parent@paragraph}{\the\c@subsubsection}
\def\checkall{\@for\next:=\sectionlist\do{
 \next\ has parent = \csname parent@\next\endcsname\\
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{One}
\checkall
\chapter{One}
\checkall
\chapter{Two}
\checkall

\section{One}
\checkall
\subsection{One}
\checkall
\subsubsection{One}
\checkall
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\checkall
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a fairly general solution based on using `expl3`'s data type `prop`. The complete code is somewhat longer than the other solutions. However, it provides a fully general solution that would work with arbitrary counter combinations out of the box.

The main idea is that in LaTeX2e there is already a good part of support for this as counters are usually reset by their parent counter. So as a starting point we assume that this reset defines the parent structure and add code to `\@addtoreset` to store the parent counter away. If that is not sufficient we provide `\setparent` to specify the parent counter by hand.

The second component we need is to provide a `\@currentcounter` in parallel to `\@currentlabel`which we add to `\refstepcounter`. Finally we provide `\builtcurrentlabel` to form a label from a counter name for typesetting (that just one of the lines from `\refstepcounter` put into a separate macro.

`\showparent` then just has to typeset the current label and a label generated from the parent counter (if any):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@addtoreset#1#2{%
   \expandafter\@cons\csname cl@#2\endcsname {{#1}}%
% NEW: store parent info
   \setparent {#1}{#2}%
}
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
% NEW: save current counter
    \protected@edef\@currentcounter{#1}%
}
% NEW: taken from refstepcounter
\def\builtcurrentlabel #1{%
       \csname p@#1\endcsname
       \csname the#1\endcsname
}
\def\showparent{%
  Current: \@currentlabel; Parent: \typesetparentlabel{\@currentcounter}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now all that remains to do is to actually store and retrieve the parent counter mappings. By the way all this has to happen before `\documentclass` so that the counters are still to be defined otherwise `\@addtoreset` would not act. So we have to use `\RequirePackage` to load expl3.

We store the parent counter name in a property list (`\g_pcnt_parent_counter_prop`) with the current counter name as key and the parent as value. The only extra complexitiy here is that a new counter without parent is added to the counter `@ckpt` (for the include mechanism) and we do not want to consider that one as a parent:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_pcnt_parent_counter_prop 
\tl_new:N \l_pcnt_result_tl

\cs_new:Npn \pcnt_store_parent_counter:nn #1#2 {
   \str_if_eq:nnF{@ckpt}{#2}
       {  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_pcnt_parent_counter_prop {#1}{#2} }
}
```

Retrieving is equally simple: if we  do not find a value we return an empty tokenlist

```
\cs_new:Npn \pcnt_get_parent_counter:nN #1#2 {
 \prop_get:NnN \g_pcnt_parent_counter_prop {#1} #2
  \quark_if_no_value:NT #2
    { \tl_clear:N #2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pcnt_get_parent_counter:nN {o} % needed below
```

Finally the interfaces: typesetting the parentlabel means retrieving the parent counter name and if not empty run it though `\builtcurrentlabel`:

```
\cs_new_eq:NN \setparent \pcnt_store_parent_counter:nn

\cs_new:Npn \typesetparentlabel #1 {
  \pcnt_get_parent_counter:oN {#1} \l_pcnt_result_tl 
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_pcnt_result_tl
     { \builtcurrentlabel{\l_pcnt_result_tl} }
}
```

And if we want we could also peak at our data structures we can define:

```
%% for tracing %%
\cs_new:Npn \showparentcounters {\prop_show:N \g_pcnt_parent_counter_prop }
\cs_new:Npn \showparentcounter #1 {
  \pcnt_get_parent_counter:nN {#1} \l_pcnt_result_tl 
  \tl_show:N  \l_pcnt_result_tl 
}
```

In the example document from the question `\showparentcounters`would produce

```
The property list \g_pcnt_parent_counter_prop contains the pairs (without
outer braces):
>  {subsection}  =>  {section}
>  {subsubsection}  =>  {subsection}
>  {paragraph}  =>  {subsubsection}
>  {subparagraph}  =>  {paragraph}.
```